# Undeifned is not a function when calling a ref in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to call a ref input in react native, and I'm keep getting `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.textInput.focus()')`

I really don't understand why, any help will be much appreciated

Here's my code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-input';

const Conatiner = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
`;

const MainText = styled.TextInput``;

export default class SignupScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Signup',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      f_name: '',
      l_name: '',
      country_code: '',
      phone: '',
    };

    this.focusLastName = this.focusLastName.bind(this);
  }

  focusLastName() {
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Conatiner>
        <MainText
          value={this.state.f_name}
          placeholder="First Name"
          returnKeyType="next"
          autoFocus
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.focusLastName();
          }}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState({ f_name: text });
          }}
        />

        <MainText
          value={this.state.l_name}
          placeholder="Last Name"
          ref={(input) => {
            this.textInput = input;
          }}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState({ l_name: text });
          }}
        />

        <PhoneInput />
      </Conatiner>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `focus()` does not exist on the `MainText` component class, it seems.  are you certain that `styled.TextInput` refers to an `HTMLElement` and not a class that wraps such an element?

Comment: Wow! great catch! Yes, this is the problem, so I now searched Google and turns out I should use innerRef instead. https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/102. Thank you so much!